# hi how do get the user to responed back,printstatment but its not allowing me to responed back

Tags: python, string, variables, input, comments

print("hello!\n")

user_name = input("what is your name?\n")

print("hello, " + user_name + "\n")

print("how are you doing?\n")

print(+ user_name + "\n")

good = "happy"

good = "sad"

good = "suicide"

if good != "happy ":
print("thats aswesome,"+ user_name + "\n")

elif good == "sad":
print("Am sorry but am a botnet,"+ user_name + "\n")

elif good == "suicide":
print("1-800 ('national Suicide Prevention')"+ user_name + "\n")

Comment: Please modify your question and format your code, do you mean you want to input the answer for "how are you doing"? I don't see an input statement after your print statement

Comment: am trying to get a prompt back after using this statement print("how are you doing "+" "+ user_name +'\n')using the if & elif statement

Comment: Of course you are not getting any prompt back because you did not implement any

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not getting a prompt back because you did not ask for any input, and you might want to define a base case for if else

```
print("hello!\n")
user_name = input("what is your name?\n")
print("hello, " + user_name + "\n")
mood = input("how are you doing? %s \n" % user_name)
if mood == "happy": print("thats aswesome,"+ user_name + "\n")
elif mood == "sad": print("Am sorry but am a botnet,"+ user_name + "\n")
elif mood == "suicide": print("1-800 ('national Suicide Prevention')"+ user_name + "\n")
else: print("Sorry I don't understand it")
```

Comment: You are missing a colon after else. You also have a space after happy and when that is removed, then the `!=` means the code wont work as intended.

Comment: yep, i believe `if mood == "happy":` would be what he wanted not  `if good != "happy ":` that he defined

Comment: thank you for your response,I will definitely try this as well.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is one of many ways to solve it:

```
print("hello!\n")
user_name = input("what is your name?\n")
print("hello, " + user_name + "\n")
print("how are you doing, " + user_name + "?\n")
good = input("""    1. happy
    2. sad
    3. suicide
""")
if good == "happy" or good == "1": print("thats aswesome, "+ user_name + "\n")
elif good == "sad" or good == "2": print("I Am sorry but I am a bot, "+ user_name + "\n")
elif good == "suicide" or good == "3": print("1-800 ('national Suicide Prevention') "+ user_name + "\n")
```

Result:

```
hello!

what is your name?
Jack
hello, Jack

how are you doing, Jack?

    1. happy
    2. sad
    3. suicide
2
I Am sorry but I am a bot, Jack

hello!

what is your name?
Jack
hello, Jack

how are you doing, Jack?

    1. happy
    2. sad
    3. suicide
happy
thats aswesome, Jack
```

Comment: wow thank you bro..Now I understand were I went wrong at you made it very clear for me simply understand.Thanks again for the help.

Comment: good morning what would be a good forum to learn how to write code for windows services and controls in Microsoft.